# Accounting for connectedness during the analysis of nodes in a directed acyclcic graph

Tags: multivariate-analysis, independence, graph-theory, networks, cross-section

I am studying a river network and environmental features measured at different stations along the network. Often, one station is higher up the river than another (or multiple others). I can essentially represent the relationships between these sample sites as a directed acyclic graph, where nodes are the sample sites and an edge exists from site A ----> site B if site A is upstream of site B.

Now, my main question: if I want to analyze changes in a set of response variables (Y) with response to environmental variables (X) at each site (i.e. multivariate analysis), is there any way I can account for the dependency between data observations? The X features are independent, as they are based on the surrounding land, but I am not sure if that is the case regarding Y.

For example, one of my Y features is crayfish population. However, if there is a large population of crayfish at site A, some of those fish may be displaced to site B. I will be analyzing the relationship of local site canopy cover and crayfish population at a single point in time (cross-sectional study), but want to be sure I am handling the DAG aspect of the sites properly.